# Get list of files

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to get a list of files on FTP folder.
The code was working when I ran it locally, but on deploying it I started receiving html instead of file name

```
ArrayList fName = new ArrayList();
try
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    //create the directory
    FtpWebRequest requestDir =
        (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(directory));
    requestDir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_USER_NAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
    requestDir.UsePassive = true;
    requestDir.UseBinary = true;
    requestDir.KeepAlive = false;
    requestDir.Proxy = null;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)requestDir.GetResponse();
    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ftpStream, Encoding.ASCII);

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        fName.Add(reader.ReadLine().ToString());
    }

    response.Close();
    ftpStream.Close();
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: I guess you mean you received URIs...Thus you need to strip the URI part to show only the file name.

Comment: I am getting the file names, but along with all it's details and  also, it is like an HTML page. I tried                             requestDir.Proxy=WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;                         but still getting HTML instead of file name directly

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `GetFileName`

```
Uri uri = new Uri(hreflink);
string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am not getting any file name, although file does exist in the folder.

Comment: @Rohan if file does not exist , you can't return file

Comment: I have checked on ftp folder. There exists a file in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the file names in a list format(not as html) by using the ip address of the ftp server and not the name

i.e.

```
ftp://xxx.x.x.xxx/folder_name/
```

instead of

```
ftp://abc.some_company.com/folder_name/
```

I will edit this answer with more details.